# Using by() function in R so that a workable list is returned

Tags: r, list, object

I am new to R and attempting to link Chess Ratings (by country) to let's say the Human Development index or something similar. I am struggling to separate the dataset into the mean ratings of countries.

```
ChessDF <- read.csv("Book3.csv", header=TRUE)
ChessDF <- ChessDF[ which(ChessDF$B.day > 1945),]
ChessMeans <- by(ChessDF$Rtng,ChessDF$Fed, mean, simplify = F)
```

Rtng = Rating, Fed = Country, and Book3/ ChessDF is my dataframe.

However, if I do this a rather useless list is returned  because it looks like this:

```
ChessDF$Fed: YEM
[1] 1818.206
----------------------------------------------------------- 
ChessDF$Fed: ZAM
[1] 1896.52
----------------------------------------------------------- 
ChessDF$Fed: ZIM
[1] 1689.874
```

I'd like to have a list that only returns the numerical values, somewhat like this:

```
1818 1896 1689 etc..
```

and then I could assign names to the values so that `YemMean = 1818` etc. Currently the list is not workable.

A solution I figured out is:

```
list2env(ChessMeans, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

This does assign numerical values to the countries, but I am having a hard time  exporting the objects from the global environment, and it seems like the wrong 
way to go about it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You could `unlist` the list output.  Please consider to show a small reproducible example and expected output.  If you need a workable list, probably, `lapply(split(ChessDF$Rtng,ChessDF$Fed), mean)`

Comment: I suggest you use `aggregate` rather than `by`.

Comment: E.g., `aggregate(Rtng ~ Fed, data = ChessDF, FUN = mean)`. The resulting data.frame is more convenient than `by` output.

Comment: Questions to SO should include minimal reproducible code which means all inputs are included and the code is self contained so anyone can copy it from your post and paste it into their session.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me. What you suggest as `1818 1896 1689 etc..` may be better described as a vector in R lingo. A list can hold vastly different structures whereas vectors, matrices and data.frames have a more rigorous form.

```
x <- by(iris[, 1], INDICES = iris$Species, FUN = mean)

str(x)

 by [1:3(1d)] 5.01 5.94 6.59
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ iris$Species: chr [1:3] "setosa" "versicolor" "virginica"
 - attr(*, "call")= language by.default(data = iris[, 1], INDICES = iris$Species, FUN = mean)

x[1]

setosa 
 5.006 

mean(x)
[1] 5.843333
```

As you can see with `str(x)`, this is actually a matrix of one dimension. You can access it like a regular vector (`x[1]`), you can even apply a function such as `mean(x)` to it. Don't be fooled by the way `x` is *printed*. Look at the structure carefully.

Similarly

```
> str(tapply(X = iris[, 1], INDEX = iris$Species, FUN = mean))
 num [1:3(1d)] 5.01 5.94 6.59
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "setosa" "versicolor" "virginica"
```

And as mentioned by others before me (see comment section) which produces a data.frame instead.

```
> str(aggregate(Sepal.Length ~ Species, FUN = mean, data = iris))
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 2 3
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.01 5.94 6.59
```

Comment: Technically, a `list` is also a vector in R (but not _atomic_)